# robotframework - invalid xpath expression

Tags: python, robotframework

Trying to get an element attribute in robotframework, like so:

`${list_id} =  Get Element Attribute  xpath://h3[contains(text(), ${name})]  data-testid`

All well and good, ${name} is a variable set higher up in the flow, but how do I wrap a variable so it is parsed as “XYZ” and not just XYZ? Without the quotes it’s an invalid xpath expression. Seen similar issues, but not many have included a variable.

Thanks,
JB

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in the quotes:

```
${list_id} = Get Element Attribute    xpath://h3[contains(text(), "${name}")]    data-testid
```

What will happen is RF will put the variable's value, and as you have quotes the xpath will end up as `//h3[contains(text(), "XYZ")]`

Comment: That was what I tried initially, but this is what I see in the console:

Element with locator 'xpath://h3[contains(text(), "$name")]' not found.

I've set it as a suite variable, maybe it's not getting passed in? Will take another look.

Comment: Sorry, it should show as ${name}, was trying to pull it in without the curly braces, but that failed too.